# How to empty contents of a log file being used by the same program

Tags: c#, file, file-io, log4net, ilog

I have a C# application which uses log4net to write some log outputs in a file names "logfile.txt" residing in the application directory. I want to empty the contents of the file as soon as it reaches a size of 10GB.

For that I'm using a timer which keeps checking whether the size of the file crosses 10GB.
But I cannot perform any operation on "logfile.txt" since it is being used by other threads to write log outputs and it's throwing me,

> System.IO.IOException "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\MyApps\TestApp1\logfile.txt' because it is being used by another process."

Here is the code of the timer which checks the size of the file "logfile.txt"

```
private void timer_file_size_check_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string log_file_path = "C:\\Program Files\\MyApps\\TestApp1\\logfile.txt";
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(log_file_path);
        bool ex;
        long s1;
        if (ex = f.Exists)
        {
            s1 = f.Length;
            if (s1 > 10737418240)
            {
                System.GC.Collect();
                System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                File.Delete(log_file_path);
                //File.Create(log_file_path).Close();
                //File.Delete(log_file_path);
                //var fs = new FileStream(log_file_path, FileMode.Truncate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MDIParent.log.Error("Log file doesn't exists..");
        }
    }
   catch (Exception er)
    {
        MDIParent.log.Error("Exceptipon :: " + er.ToString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: you mixed up try/catch. Do the catching under the try statement

Comment: Why don't you reconfigure the application to maintain a logfile size of no more than 10 GB? You can do this with a `RollingFileAppender` and the `maximumFileSize` option. The whole point of log4net is that it gives you the flexibility to configure logging independently from application logic.

Comment: MDIParent.log is a ILog type member that writes the respective logs to the file "logfile.txt". What i want to do is empty the contents of this file when the size reaches 10GB.

Comment: @ Jeroen Mostert can you guide me through the solution u gave?

Comment: Do i need to change the log config from app.config where i have made other log configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't delete a log file on your own because log4net can do it for you. If you use `RollingFileAppender` you can specify the maximum file size (`maximumFileSize`  property). Additionally if you set `maxSizeRollBackups` property to 0, then the log file will be truncated when it reaches the limit. Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641226/maximum-filesize-of-logfileappender-in-log4net) for an example.